# Linq not returning data from database

Tags: c#, linq

Im trying to use linq to return a row from my SQL database on Azure.

```
PracticeDBDataSet database = new PracticeDBDataSet();   

var movieQuery = from a in database.movieDB_Movie
                 select a;
```

I get nothing back even though I have records in my DB (I can see the data using the Preview Data tool in Visual Studio). Debugging my code and looking at the results view of movieQuery says

> "Empty, "Enumeration yielded no results"

Any ideas?

Comment: make sure your sql connect string is correct

Comment: I set up my connection using the connect to database wizard in Visual Studio. Do you know where the connection string is stored? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Should be stored in the config file

Comment: Thanks. Yes the connection string is all correct.

Comment: Check also this things: 
If context that provide you data from azure db is open.
If user that is authorized by azure db exists, and has rights to get data.